# Starting an android service on power on or restart of device

Tags: java, android, service, broadcast, boot

I am a beginner in android guys.So, I need your help, I created an android service and I want to restart that service when the device powered-on or restarts only in the situation when my service is activated.
In case my service is deactivated it shouldn't be started on device being powered-on or restarting of device.
Please help
Thanks

Comment: this is not a duplicate,first try to grasp it.

Answer (score 0):

To restart your service you can create a BrodcastReciever with the action `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and inside it, simply start your Service. And you can use SharedPreferences to save if the service was running on shutdown or not.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a way to indicate whether or not the service is activated. In this case, I'd use a `SharedPreference`, which is stored persistently even after the app is closed, device is rebooted, etc. You can do that like so:

```
public void setServiceActivated(boolean activated) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("servicePrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    prefEditor.putBoolean("serviceActivated", activated);
    prefEditor.apply();
}
```

Then, create a `BroadcastReceiver`, which will run when the device bootup process is completed, and will start your service if it is activated:

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Method is called after device bootup is complete
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent arg1) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("servicePrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean serviceActivated = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("serviceActivated", false);

        if (serviceActivated) {
            // Start service here
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- Launches your service on device boot-up -->
    <receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: thnxx for the help..

Comment: please help me with this.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338079/horizontal-layout-for-viewpager-not-inflating?noredirect=1#comment85676418_49338079

Comment: hey nope could you help me with this???   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50217950/about-us-screen-pop-up-using-3-dots-action-bar-button